# Parsing XML and taking values from the file

Tags: regex, xml, parsing, classification, grouping

I need to get exact answer from my whole .xml file. 
Let's say we have part of my .xml:

```
<trace>
        <string key="concept:name" value="1"/>
        <string key="description" value="Simulated process instance"/>
        <event>
            <string key="org:resource" value="System"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:23:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Register"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="org:resource" value="Tester3"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:23:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Analyze Defect"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="start"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="defectType" value="6"/>
            <string key="org:resource" value="Tester3"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
            <string key="phoneType" value="T2"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:30:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Analyze Defect"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="org:resource" value="SolverC1"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:31:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Repair (Complex)"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="start"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="org:resource" value="SolverC1"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:49:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Repair (Complex)"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="org:resource" value="Tester3"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:49:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Test Repair"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="start"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="numberRepairs" value="0"/>
            <string key="org:resource" value="Tester3"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T12:55:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Test Repair"/>
            <string key="defectFixed" value="true"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="   " value="System"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T13:10:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Inform User"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
        </event>
        <event>
            <string key="numberRepairs" value="0"/>
            <string key="org:resource" value="System"/>
            <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="complete"/>
            <date key="time:timestamp" value="1970-01-02T13:10:00.000+01:00"/>
            <string key="concept:name" value="Archive Repair"/>
            <string key="defectFixed" value="true"/>
        </event>
    </trace>
```

From here I need to find two exact "events". Event name is written in trace -> event -> string key="concept:name" value="**EVENT NAME**"

One of these events should have **lifecycle:transition** value="start", second one - "complete".

From "complete" event I need to take **time:timestamp** value="time" and subtract "start" event **time:timestamp** value="time".

So as you see the formula is `time = time_complete - time_start`

The problem is that time (time-date) format is not useful so from, e.g. `1970-01-02T12:30:00.000+01:00` I need to get only `12:30:00` and make it subtractable to find exact time how much the process took.

My idea it to get all event names in trace, all lifecycle transition values, and all "times" in this trace but I see that it's too difficult and I can find the proper way to do it. Here is some code from what I did:

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("trace");
        Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
        NodeList stringList = element.getElementsByTagName("string");

        NodeList dateList = element.getElementsByTagName("date");

        //--- Get all events names ---//

        for (int x = 1, size = stringList.getLength(); x < size; x++) {
            if (stringList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue().contains("concept:name")) {
                eventName.add(stringList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue());
            }
        }

        //--- Get all times of every event in trace ---//

        for (int y = 0, size = dateList.getLength(); y < size; y++) {
            if (dateList.item(y).getAttributes().getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue().contains("time:timestamp")) {
                time.add(dateList.item(y).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue());
            }
        }

        //--- Get all lifecycle transitions of events ---//

        for (int x = 0, size = stringList.getLength(); x < size; x++) {
            if (stringList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue().contains("lifecycle:transition")) {
                status.add(stringList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank for the information but I'm not trying to parse XML using regex. I know how to parse and how to get value from attribute. Let's say I have a value of this 1970-01-02T12:31:00.000+01:00
I need to get only time with format HH:MM:SS and make it subtractable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that I solved my problem using the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+'SS:SS");
            Date data;

            for (int i = 0; i < time.size(); i++) {

                data = str.parse(time.get(i));
                minutes.add(data.getHours() * 60 + data.getMinutes());
            }
```

Anyway, thank you for your help :)